# How to back track a two dimensional array in C?

Tags: arrays, c, multidimensional-array, cell

So I am building a matrix table with x rows and y columns. Once the program outputs the matrix table, it needs to back track the following and store the current x value in a different array called "track":

1. start at arr[x][y] as in start at the right most bottom corner of the matrix
2. go up by n1 values
3. go left n2 value

If the program reaches arr[0][0], the program exits the process and prints all the stores values in the track array.

[image]

As per this example, the program will start at arr[2][3] (right most bottom corner). Then it will go up by n1 value which is a user input and then go left by n2 value. Each time, the array is back traced, the current x value will be stored in the "track" array.

Here's the code I have so far:

```
#include<stdio.h>
  
int main(void)
{
    // an array with 3 rows and 2 columns.
    int n1;
    int n2;
    int track[10] = {0};
    int arr[3][2] = {{0,1}, {2,3}, {4,5}};
   

     //user input 
     printf("Enter n1 value:");
     scanf("%d", &n1);


     printf("Enter n1 value:");
     scanf("%d", &n1);


    // output each array element's value
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < 2; j++)
        {
            printf("Element at arr[%i][%i]: ",i, j);
            printf("%d\n",arr[i][j]);
        }
    }
  
   //perform backtrack of two dimensional array here 
    
}
```

Comment: So the user can only navigate up and to the left? What happens when they reach the top left cell - where can they go?

Comment: I am sorry I didn't specify this. If the program reaches arr[0][0], the program exits and prints all the values in the track array.

Comment: Have you made an attempt to solve this on your own? If so, can we please see it? Generally speaking, this is not a *do-my-homework* type of site. We like to see a genuine effort to solve the problem. This question is well presented, but the example code is more-or-less [boilerplate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boilerplate_text), and lacks a serious attempt.